# Measure of $x$-section and $y$-section

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I need some help in the following question

> **Exercise**. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N},\nu)$ complete and $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If $E\in\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$ and $\mu\times\nu(E)=0$, show that if $F\subset E$, then $\nu(F_x)=0$ $x$-a.e. and $\mu(F^y)=0$ $y$-a.e..

In Folland's book, the Exercise 49.(a) from chapter 2 propose to us show that if $E$ satisfies the same conditions above, then $\nu(E_x)=\mu(E^y)=0$ a.e.. Well, this is very easy to prove by usying Theorem 2.36.

My idea to solve the **Exercise** is observe that since $F\subset E$ it follows that $F_x\subset E_x$ and $F^y\subset E^y$, for all $x\in X,y\in Y$, and use de completeness of $\mu$ and $\nu$. But looks like I missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int \nu(E_x) d\mu (x)=(\mu \times \nu) (E)=0$. So $\nu(E_x) =0\,  a.e. [\mu]$. Since $F_x \subset E_x$ and $\nu$ is complete it follows that $F_x$ is $\nu-$ measurable and $\nu(F_x)=0$. Similar argument for $F^{y}$.